# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, json, angularjs, angularjs-controller

```
    TestApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {


    $http.get('test.php')
        .success(function(data){
            var qwerty = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(qwerty)
        });


}])
```

это angularjs которий делает запрось test.php

```
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];
$arr = json_encode($arr);
return $arr;
```

а в итоге ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test.php должен выводить информацию:

```
echo $arr;
```

а не возвращать ее через

```
return $arr;
```